# `Could not make proto path relative` for protoc.js

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, emscripten, protobuf.js

#### Question

In my C++ project, I use protobuf to generate some files with calling `protobuf_generate_cpp` cmake macro.  The generate make file is like:

```
cd /Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/tools/converter/src && /Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/_deps/protobuf-build/protoc -I/Users/bob/cmake-build-debug/tools/converter/src --cpp_out=./ /Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/tools/converter/src/module/a.proto
```

This works and the file hierarchy is:

```
cmake-build-debug/toos/converter/src/module/a.proto
```

When I use `emcmake` and `emmake` to build this same project, I got generated make files:

```
/Users/bob/code/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin/node --experimental-wasm-threads /Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/_deps/protobuf-build/protoc.js -I/Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/pnn/tools/converter/src --cpp_out=./ /Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/tools/converter/src/module/a.proto
```

But I got error:

```
Users/bob/code/cmake-build-debug/tools/converter/src: warning: directory does not exist.
Could not make proto path relative: module/a.proto: No such file or directory
```

But why? I have googled a lot. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. If any one has same problem, you can cite this and see if it helps.

The error is arisen that `protoc.js` has no permisson to access file system. So enable the `protoc` target in CMake  with node raw file system will solve this:

```
set_target_properties(protoc PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-sNODERAWFS=1")
```

Comment: Should be noted that protoc itself behaves rather weird with relative paths.